# Weird behavior when loading string from input

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function, that shall send some message to the server. Sending the message works quite fine, neverthless I'm not able to load the message from standard input with spaces...So when I  type `"Hello world!"`, then I get as an output this:

```
*******Hello********
*******World!********
```

I'm quite new to `C++` and this behavior is quite surprising to me. Would anybody explain me, why is this so, and how to fix it?

```
void * Client::sendMessage(void *threadid) {
    string message;
    const char * c;
    char buffer[200];
    int fd = (long) threadid;
    while (true) {
        cin >> message;
        if (message == "exit") {
            break;
        }
        cout<<"*******"<<message<<"********"<<endl; 
        c = message.c_str();
        strncpy(buffer, c, sizeof ( buffer));       
        send(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: `cin >> message` stops reading at whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cin input is space delimited.  If you wish to input the whole line, use something like

```
getline (cin,message);
```

Answer (score 2):

cin breaks string input by spaces.  You'd likely prefer to either input into a byte buffer or use [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline) to break by line breaks.